# Is a virtual server enough for a video uploading platform or do I need a hosting like AWS and Oracle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualhost, hosting, bandwidth, website

I am developing a platform where the users can upload videos, ask for videos and download the videos uploaded by other users.
I have developed the platform using Java Spring Boot, Angular and MongoDB and everything works on my localhost perfectly.
However, I don't know which kind of server I should rent because I don't know how many users will use my platform, how many simultaneous uploads/downloads I will have, etc.
The platform is for academic people (professors, students, etc.).
I have the following options in mind:

1. Virtual server,  Linux V10
   8 GB RAM
   300 GB SSD
   4 CPU vCore
   8 GB RAM garantiert
   connection up to 100 MBit/s
   Traffic Unlimited
2. Virtual server,  Linux V30
   16 GB RAM
   500 GB SSD
   6 CPU vCore
   16 GB RAM garantiert
   connection up to 500 MBit/s
   Traffic Unlimited

Is one of these options enough for the beginning in my case? How can I make an estimation?

If I rent a traditional virtual server and 5000 people want to upload videos simultaneously, what happens? How does it affect the loading speed of the website? Does it slow down everything?

Is the number of viewers also a bottleneck or just the number of simultaneous upload/download of files would be the bottleneck? For how many viewers/simultaneous uploads and downloads is it okay to have a traditional virtual server?

It would be good if anyone could give me a hint how I can make an estimation. I have totally no idea how I should go on.

Comment: You should consider looking into some cloud training as one of the advantages is that you (to some extent) don't have to worry about capacity if you choose the right services. You could run your service using AWS Elastic Beanstalk & S3 for example, and it should scale fairly automatically.

Comment: 5000 concurrent uploads on either of these will be farcically slow, you need more bandwidth

Comment: If cost was not the major driver I would approach this using managed services. For example CloudFront CDN, S3 for video storage, lambda serverless compute. Bandwidth can be _very_ expensive in AWS at volume, so it might be cheaper to use Lightsail or Digital Ocean with the more traditional approach you've taken. Or a standard server with cheaper bulk storage like BackBlaze B2 that has plenty of bandwidth.